# Java Object passing through sockets

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

How do you pass an unserialized class from a 3rd party library to a serialized one?

What I'm trying to do is pass objects from a server down to a client through a socket. I understand that only serialized objects are interpretable from the end of a client.

So if I had a Class ExtA from library extA, can I make a Class MyClassA and just extend ExtA?

Is there a simple way to do this other than touching the 3rd party library?

Thanks! :)

Comment: You need to pass only visible data? Or you need to mantains something like a status of the 3rd library object?

Comment: Copy the state of the non-serializable object to a serializable one, and serialize this other object.

Comment: If the class isn't Serializable, no, you have to touch it somehow. What's the data you're passing? Often, you're better off serializing with JSON than Java's built-in serialization.

Comment: Note that not only must the base class be serializable but also all non-transient objects referenced from it.

Comment: Create a clone of same object. Then you can copy properties by using BeanUtils that comes from apache. After that you can implement Serializable on your own object.

Comment: Hi All. I'm passing Cisco objects from JTAPI. https://developer.cisco.com/site/jtapi/overview/ @DavideLorenzoMARINO It's not just visible data but data underneath a specific class.

Comment: @HannoBinder: that is true that's why this problem has been bugging me for a day now. I can't find an elegant solution as to how to implement this part.

Comment: @SercanOzdemir: I'm reading through it and it seems like if cloning is the way to go, then I have to clone all the classes that may have inherited the specific object that I am trying to pass on. That is another problem if I go down that path.

Comment: Do you need the actual object structures on the remote side? Or can you just extract the relevant values from the structure and transmit only those, possibly in your own serializable class? Also, as others have noted, some generic serialization framework, e.g. for JSON or XML, may be able to help you, and if if doesn't you could still try to roll your own implementation using reflection and recursively walking through the object graph; just make sure you handle cycles gracefully.

Comment: You can also have a look at the implementation of `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Object, boolean)` and possibly copy it while excluding the `if (obj instanceof Serializable)` check. Still no guarantee that the objects will work out as expected on the other side because they just weren't designed to.

Comment: @HannoBinder: i'm actually looking at JSON implementation. The thing about recursion though is the one I'm quite questionable of. I mean the performance of serializing an object would be too slow going down that level. What I'm doing now is manually getting the data from the 3rd party libraries and writing my own serialized class; putting all the data I need from the 3rd party library to it. It's quite a hassle though. :(